# PrimeFaces charts

Tags: jsf, primefaces, pie-chart

I am newbie to JSF primefaces.

I want to know how to configure web.xml and faces-config.xml for pie charts. Any sample code with these 2 xml files will also be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Primeface's latest stable release 2.2.1 do the following:

Put Primefaces jar file and the jar file of your preferred theme in your project classpath.

Add the following to your *web.xml* and replace the `<param-value>` content with the name of your selected theme:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>cupertino</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Add the following to all of your facelets `html` tags that use primefaces components:

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
```

e.g:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
```

No change in *faces-config.xml* needed.

If you should be using an older version of primefaces the procedure is a bit different.